# Use HttpClientFactory in netstandard2.0 library without access to ServicesCollection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, httpclient, autofac

W have a project that is being shipped in form of a Nuget package that is inteded to be consumed by other applications in our system. The idea was that library provided a set of services and was exposing Autofac extension method `public static ContainerBuilder UseMyLibrary(this ContainerBuilder builder)`. Now, this design predates porting our applications do .net core but we kept the Autofac config, so the consumer applications use Autofac/ServiceCollection integration. Now, we need our library to perform HTTP calls, so we wanted to use `HttpClientFactory`. But as I read in docs - in order to use one we need to call `AddHttpClient();` on the `ServiceCollection` which we don't have access to in the library thus requiring the consumer (typically ASP.NET Core app) to call it in `Startup.ConfigureServices`. Is there a way we can confiugre `HttpClientFactory`in our `public static ContainerBuilder UseMyLibrary(this ContainerBuilder builder)` method?
`

Comment: The only real way to do this is to create a `ServiceCollection` yourself, add HttpClientFactory to it, build the service provider from the service collection, and then resolve `IHttpClientFactory` from it. The implementation is internal, so there's no way to just create the required services without resorting to reflection.

Comment: Why don't you let the consuming application call `.AddHttpClient()`. You can describe this in the documentation of your package or might even be able to do some runtime checks and throw an expressive exception when you notice the required dependencies are missing.

Comment: If a lib needs to register Services, I tend to make a IServiceCollection Extension Method , for example `public static void AddMyLib(this IServiceCollection services){ <your DI setup here> }`. Client app just needs to call services.AddMyLib() then.

Comment: @MartinCostello that's one approach I'm goingo to try :)

Comment: @Steven that's perfectly valid approach, I'm just exploring if it's even possible to achieve internally

Comment: @Fildor Yes, eventaully we'd like to get rid of Autofac and just lean on this approach, but for the time being we need some short-term solution while Autofac is still in place (like lfor now ibraries use other libraries that are configured using Autofac)

Comment: @AndrzejD I am pretty sure, a similar approach would work for Autofac. Just look at some libraries that have extra nugets for different DI Frameworks. They'd do something of that sort just implemented as expected by the respective container.

Comment: ^^ Nevermind, I just realized, I missed the problem. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Microsoft's DefaultHttpClientFactory is an internal class and is tightly coupled to Microsoft's DI (with IHttpClientFactory)..

For alternatives, you can check this out from Microsoft's docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0#alternatives-to-ihttpclientfactory

So you can actually create a simple factory yourself using SocketsHttpHandler class, here's an example:

```
public static class HttpClientFactory
{
    static SocketsHttpHandler SocketsHttpHandler;
    static HttpClientFactory()
    {
        SocketsHttpHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler();
    }

    public static HttpClient CreateClient()
    {
        return new HttpClient(SocketsHttpHandler, false);
    }
}
```

Using static class will insure that a single SocketsHttpHandler is used for the lifetime of the app, and no need to worry about creating a thread safe singleton with double lock check etc..